# Library with standard(ish) type for representing decimal fractions

Tags: gratis, open-source, library, software-development, c++

I would like to be able to express decimal fractions (i.e. m * 10^{-k} for integers m,k ) with exact precision - as opposed to what we have with binary floating-point values. Essentially there are two options: Floating-point, but decimal (as in [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3871.html)), or fixed point with only the mantissa stored.

So I'm after a library which implements one of these options, or both, reasonably.

Requirements:

- Gratis
- Header-mostly
- LGPL or similar lax FOSS license
- Not abandoned

Desirable:

- Header-only
- As fast as one could expect given the lack of hardware support for this
- Well-documented
- C++11/C++14-oriented
- No significant external dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [**The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library**](https://gmplib.org/) (GMP) possibly with **[The GNU MPFR Library](http://www.mpfr.org/)** which are C libraries for multiple-precision floating-point computations with correct rounding.

There are bindings for [C++](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html#C_002b_002b-Class-Interface) and other languages.

- Gratis
- Open Source GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL v 3)
- Latest release at the time of writing: GMP 16 December 2016 & MPFR 27 September 2016 but the VCS shows checkins this week for both.
- [Documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/index.html#Top) looks good
- MPFR depends on GMP

Comment: IIANM, The GMP library does not offer either one of the types I asked for. The closest thing they offer are rationals and that's not really what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the [mpdecimal](http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/) package or its underlying [libmpdec](http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/doc/libmpdec/index.html) library, which is "a complete implementation of the General Decimal Arithmetic Specification".

Moreover, the [proposal page](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3871.html) you linked to already lists some other implementations, notably from [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library/) and [IBM](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decnumber.html).